# How to make gallery photos even in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my code for a gallery on the website that I am making

```
<h3>Gallery</h3>
<?php
include"includes/connection.php"; 
$sql = "select * from kategorije";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
?>

<h4 class="text-center"><?php echo ucwords($row['naziv']); ?></h4>
<?php
    $id = $row['sifra'];
    $sql1 = "select * from rad where kategorija = $id";

    $res1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($res1);
    if($n>0)
    {
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1))
        {
            $pid = $row1['sifra']; 
?>
        <div class="col-md-2 col_1">
            <a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $pid ?>"><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row1['datoteka']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
        </div>
<?php
        }
    }else{
?>
        <div class="col-md-2 col_1">
            <h6>No Images</h6>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I need to make that all the photos in gallery have same height and width when they are uploaded, but I don't know how. I tried to insert this code, but it just doesn't work:

```
echo"<img src='$dir_path$files[$i]'style='width:150px;height:200px;'>
```

Also I tried in CSS but it won't work either.

Comment: did you echo $row?is okey?

Comment: Do you want them to be UPLADED with the same height and width, or only DISPALYED with the same height and width? Display would be quite easy, for uploading it will be a bit more difficult.

Comment: DISPALYED! ... They are uploaded nicely and that part works

Comment: 1) You waste bandwidth displaying large images and using CSS to shrink them 2) If you use CSS to resize them, and the originals are a different SHAPE you will distort the images

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: RiggsFolly, thanks! I will try to fix that... I am new at this and still struggling... I just wonder what to add to gallery to make photos displayed even

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to display them in another size, you can achieve this by the way you tried, but with the correct syntax. I hope its this line of code where you want the resized image:

```
<a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $pid ?>"><img src="uploads/<?php echo `$row1['datoteka']; ?>" class="img-responsive" height="200" width="150" alt=""/></a>`
```

Let me know it it worked for you. It this wasen't the line you want to do it, keep in mind you simply have to follow the syntax:

```
<img src="http://url.com/pic.png" width="150" height="200">
```

Thats all. :)

Comment: Twinfriends ,thank you! it is still not all photos the same, but it does look much better!

Comment: @rand Thats quite weird. Normally they should all have the same size / height right now. But for sure, if they were uploaded with a white border or something, you may think they haven't the same size. If you're working with google chrome, right click on the picture and then "inspect" then you're going to see some more information about the pic.